# Shapes (398,398) and (1,4) are not aligned error while adapting a neuronal network to using breast cancer database

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to fit a neuronal network code to make it use the sklearn breast cancer database. This is the code I have tryed:

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot


class NeuronLayer():
    def __init__(self, number_of_neurons, number_of_inputs_per_neuron):
        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((number_of_inputs_per_neuron, number_of_neurons)) - 1


class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self, layer1, layer2):
        self.layer1 = layer1
        self.layer2 = layer2

    # The Sigmoid function, which describes an S shaped curve.
    # We pass the weighted sum of the inputs through this function to
    # normalise them between 0 and 1.
    def __sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

    # The derivative of the Sigmoid function.
    # This is the gradient of the Sigmoid curve.
    # It indicates how confident we are about the existing weight.
    def __sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    # We train the neural network through a process of trial and error.
    # Adjusting the synaptic weights each time.
    def train(self, training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, number_of_training_iterations):
        for iteration in range(0, number_of_training_iterations):
            # Pass the training set through our neural network
            output_from_layer_1, output_from_layer_2 = self.think(training_set_inputs)

            # Calculate the error for layer 2 (The difference between the desired output
            # and the predicted output).
            layer2_error = training_set_outputs - output_from_layer_2
            layer2_delta = layer2_error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output_from_layer_2)

            # Calculate the error for layer 1 (By looking at the weights in layer 1,
            # we can determine by how much layer 1 contributed to the error in layer 2).
            layer1_error = layer2_delta.dot(self.layer2.synaptic_weights.T)
            layer1_delta = layer1_error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output_from_layer_1)

            # Calculate how much to adjust the weights by
            layer1_adjustment = training_set_inputs.T.dot(layer1_delta)
            layer2_adjustment = output_from_layer_1.T.dot(layer2_delta)

            # Adjust the weights.
            self.layer1.synaptic_weights += layer1_adjustment
            self.layer2.synaptic_weights += layer2_adjustment

    # The neural network thinks.
    def think(self, inputs):
        output_from_layer1 = self.__sigmoid(dot(inputs, self.layer1.synaptic_weights))
        output_from_layer2 = self.__sigmoid(dot(output_from_layer1, self.layer2.synaptic_weights))
        return output_from_layer1, output_from_layer2

    # The neural network prints its weights
    def print_weights(self):
        print ("    Layer 1 (4 neurons, each with 3 inputs): ")
        print (self.layer1.synaptic_weights)
        print ("    Layer 2 (1 neuron, with 4 inputs):")
        print (self.layer2.synaptic_weights)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Leer el dataset
    db_breast_cancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()

    # Creamos los conjuntos de entrenamiento y test.
    conjunto_de_datos = db_breast_cancer.data # Las características del conjunto de datos
    target = db_breast_cancer.target # Los targets del conjunto de datos
    tamanio_conjunto_test = 0.30 # Tamaño para el conjunto de test en %
    numero_semilla = 7 # Semilla para generar aleatoriedad
    rango_a_estudiar = range(0, 30) # Seleccionar un rango de ejecuciones del algoritmo

    # Separar conjunto de datos en entrenamiento y test
    training_set_inputs, \
    test_set_inputs, \
    training_set_outputs, \
    test_set_outputs = \
        model_selection.train_test_split(
            conjunto_de_datos, 
            target, 
            test_size=tamanio_conjunto_test, 
            random_state=numero_semilla
        )

    #Seed the random number generator
    random.seed(1)

    # Create layer 1 (4 neurons, each with 30 inputs)
    layer1 = NeuronLayer(4, 30)

    # Create layer 2 (a single neuron with 4 inputs)
    layer2 = NeuronLayer(1, 4)

    # Combine the layers to create a neural network
    neural_network = NeuralNetwork(layer1, layer2)

    print ("Stage 1) Random starting synaptic weights: ")
    neural_network.print_weights()

    # The training set. We have 7 examples, each consisting of 3 input values
    # and 1 output value.
#training_set_inputs = array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
#training_set_outputs = array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]).T

    # Train the neural network using the training set.
    # Do it 60,000 times and make small adjustments each time.
    neural_network.train(training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs.T, 60000)

    print ("Stage 2) New synaptic weights after training: ")
    neural_network.print_weights()

    # Test the neural network with a new situation.
    print ("Stage 3) Considering a new situation [1, 1, 0] -> ?: ")
    hidden_state, output = neural_network.think(test_set_input[0])
    print (output)
```

But I get next error:

> ValueError: shapes (398,398) and (1,4) not aligned: 398 (dim 1) != 1
>   (dim 0).

More explecitly, the error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-335a2d34ac99> in <module>()
    103     # Train the neural network using the training set.
    104     # Do it 60,000 times and make small adjustments each time.
--> 105     neural_network.train(training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs.T, 60000)
    106 
    107     print ("Stage 2) New synaptic weights after training: ")

<ipython-input-9-335a2d34ac99> in train(self, training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, number_of_training_iterations)
     38             # Calculate the error for layer 1 (By looking at the weights in layer 1,
     39             # we can determine by how much layer 1 contributed to the error in layer 2).
---> 40             layer1_error = layer2_delta.dot(self.layer2.synaptic_weights.T)
     41             layer1_delta = layer1_error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output_from_layer_1)
     42 

ValueError: shapes (398,398) and (1,4) not aligned: 398 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Any idea how could I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand what the error means? You're multiplying matrices of dimensions that don't match (a 398 x 398 matrix cannot be multiplied by a 1 x 4 matrix)

Comment: Yes,  I know.  I have solved it But it continues not working,  i get no error But I always get 1 as output